# how to pass a value as a parameter while calling a jquery function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

```
function getReportGroups() {
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "ReportGroups.ashx",
        data: {
            'method': 'getReportGroups',
            'projectId': '30390'
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('inside success');
            var i = 0;
            groupName = [data[i].name];
            while (data[i] != null) {
                alert([data[i].name]);
                alert([data[i].reportGroupId]);
                $("#top-node").append("<li item-checked='true' item-expanded='true'><a href=# style=font-weight:bold>" + [data[i].name] + "</a>");
                i++;
                var id = [data[i].reportGroupId];
                getReports(id);
            }

        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error- Inside the error loop");
        }

    });
}

function getReports(id) {
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "ReportGroups.ashx",
        data: {
            'method': 'getReports',
            'reportGroupId': id
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('inside getReports success');
            var i = 0;
            groupName = [data[i].name];
            while (data[i] != null) {
                alert([data[i].name]);
                i++;
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error- Inside the error loop");
        }
    });
}
```

This is my code.
Here when i call the getReports(id) from the getReportGroups() with the parameter id, the id is passed as zero in the getReoprts() function. I don know whats the problem. i used an alert box to check whether the 'id' exist in the first one, it does.. I have a valid Id in the getReportsFunction. But i am getting the id as zero in the second. What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Why are you wrapping variables in arrays like `groupName = [data[i].name]`? I would begin tracking the problem from there...

Comment: You are declaring var id in the success call of the first method.  Maybe declare it outside of the ajax call- so make it outside the ajax call scope, just after getReportGroups.  Also, where do you alert that the id is correct when you are in getReports?

Comment: @Ebenezar_Gislen_Softwares that's in getReportGroups, not in getReports.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're incrementing `i` before calling `var id = data[i].reportGroupId`, where as you test the value on the first iteration (`alert([data[i].reportGroupId]`);).

Move `i++` as the last statement of the while loop and see if this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem looks like `i++`, you can use .each() to iterate through the data

```
$.each(data, function(idx, item){
    alert(item.name);
    alert([item.reportGroupId]);
    $("#top-node").append("<li item-checked='true' item-expanded='true'><a href=# style=font-weight:bold>" + [item.name] + "</a>");
    var id = [item.reportGroupId];
    getReports(id);

})
```